# Replacing inline css - not as simple as it may look

Tags: javascript, css

Ok, so listen. I got something like this:

```
<div class="theinsideofclass" style="theinsideofstyle" ...></div>
<div class="theinsideofclass" style="theinsideofstyle" ...></div>
<div class="theinsideofclass" style="theinsideofstyle" ...></div>
<div class="theinsideofclass" style="theinsideofstyle" ...></div>
```

And they are dynamically changed(each time in different time) and I don't have any control of the source code.

The thing is, I want simply override the `theinsideofstyle`, but all my attempts are failed. I tried with the `!important;` but it didn't go. Isn't it suppose to override the inline css? Anyway, what are my options here? Obviously simple JS won't help me here as the entire `divs` are changed/replaced each time with the same code.

Just shoot with any idea, folks... Perhaps it will navigate for some solution.

Comment: share your css you used..

Comment: We might need more idea of your actual CSS and HTML. but it sounds like you are not targeting your CSS in the right way if `!important` is not working

Comment: this is not enough information for us. show us an example for `theinsideofstyle`

Comment: Are you ok with jQuery solution for the same ?

Comment: please shoot up your code or a link to inspect the situation in a better way.

Comment: Ali, shoot, i'll give a try. This probably won't change much, divs are replace the changed code... `MutationObserver` may do the trick, but I don't wanna use it. Anyway, show me what you think. @Gaurav, Andrew, lolka... I know how to target it, mates. It's something else.

Comment: Make sure you add `!important` to every declaration, not only the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some JS that is executed once the entire page is loaded, with all resources loaded, etc:

```js
function load() 
{
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("theinsideofclass");
    for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].removeAttribute("style");
     }
}
window.onload = load;
```

```css
.theinsideofclass {
  color: green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="theinsideofclass" style="color: red;">
  My inline style is color: black
</div>
<div class="theinsideofclass" style="color: red;">
  My inline style is color: black
</div>
<div class="theinsideofclass" style="color: red;">
  My inline style is color: black
</div>
```

As you can see, without the JS the inline style (font color of red) would normally override the external CSS style (green). However, my JS is removing the `style` attribute from the elements with the class of `theinsideofclass` so you can style with normal CSS **WITHOUT** using `!important` (I never use `!important` unless all my other options are exhausted).

Comment: I tried it, but the `divs` are generates each time. Once this fired, the divs are coming back in a couple of moments and all starts from begining...

Comment: @yuvubalazo Ah, I see - I thought you meant they're dynamically generated on page load. Are they generated on the fly?

Comment: np. Yes, on the fly.

Comment: @yuvubalazo What event triggers the creation of the dynamically generated elements? You could execute the function once that's been triggered...

Answer (score 0):

Hey you could wrap the elements in a div and loop through them + add a custom class which you could then use to define style to these divs.

PLEASE NOTE: I assume by your question that the css-class is also dynamic/changing and you have no control of it.

HTML:

```
<div id="outerdiv">
  <div class="theinsideofclass" style="theinsideofstyle"></div>
  <div class="theinsideofclass" style="theinsideofstyle"></div>
  <div class="theinsideofclass" style="theinsideofstyle"></div>
  <div class="theinsideofclass" style="theinsideofstyle"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var children = document.getElementById('outerdiv').children;

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var child = children[i];
  child.classList.add('myclass'); // this will add the class "myclass" to all the children divs inside the outerdiv
}
```

CSS:

```
.myclass {
  background-color: red !important; // which ever style you want to overwrite
}
```

You could even go as far as removing the `style` attribute from the div with:

```
child.removeAttribute('style');
```

This way you won't need to use the `!important` in your css.

**EDIT:**

Based on OP's comment.

You could also try wrapping all these divs in an outer div, if you can control where they are rendered:

```
<div id="outerdiv">
  <div class="theinsideofclass" style="theinsideofstyle"></div>
  <div class="theinsideofclass" style="theinsideofstyle"></div>
  <div class="theinsideofclass" style="theinsideofstyle"></div>
  <div class="theinsideofclass" style="theinsideofstyle"></div>
</div>
```

Then in your css:

```
#outerdiv > div {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but the `divs` are generates each time. Once this fired, the divs are coming back in a couple of moments and all starts from begining...

Comment: So you have these divs generated every n seconds and all of them have random class and style?

Comment: Not class, but styles, yes. And the n(t=time) is changed too. Eeach time for each slide.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can set style attribute to blank like below:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.theinsideofclass').attr('style','');

});
```

Kinda working demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/nm77md0L/ , https://jsfiddle.net/nm77md0L/1/

Comment: if you inspect and check style attribute of  div with class `theinsideofclass` will be blank

Answer (score 0):

Since `div`s are generated on the fly and recreated when `style` attribute gets removed, try using `setProperty` on its [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) with third argument set to `important`.

```js
//document.getElementsByClassName("theinsideofclass")[0].setAttribute('style', 'color: purple !important'); // recreates div
document.getElementsByClassName("theinsideofclass")[0].style.setProperty('color', 'blue', 'important'); // maybe won't?
```

```css
.theinsideofclass{color: green !important}
```

```html
<div class="theinsideofclass" style="color: red !important">TXT</div>
```

I can't guarantee it will work since we can't see what causes the divs to get regenerated and how, but give it a try, maybe the code is recreated when `style` attribute changes directly.